# Holder continuity of $\frac{x}{|x|^3} \ast f$ with $f \in C^1_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convolution, holder-spaces

Ok, so I need to show that for $f \in C^1_0(\mathbb{R}^3)$ the convolution with $k(x) := \frac{x}{|x|^3}$ is Holder continuous. The exponent doesn't matter much as long as I can bound it using quantities like $||f||_{\infty}$ or $||f||_{L^1}$ - same goes for the Holder norm.

I've managed to show that there is a constant $C$ such that
$$ |E(x) - E(y)| \leq |x-y| \ln (\frac{1}{|x-y|})$$
as long as $|x-y| \leq e^{-1}$, but I don't really know if that helps with anything. We could use it to show the Holder 'continuity' for$x$ and $y$'s close to eachother, but this doesn't help at all for those that are further away.

Comment: Without thinking much about your problem: If you could show that your function is bounded, then Hoelder continuity for $x,y$ close is enough (for the others use $|E(x) - E(y)|\leq 2 \Vert E \Vert_\infty$).

Comment: thanks @PhoemueX, I can't believe I missed this, that helps a lot! if you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it so that the question doesn't pop up in the 'unanswered' queue anymore, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in my comment, you can use the easy bound

$$
|E(x) - E(y)| \leq \frac{2}{C^\alpha} \Vert E \Vert_\infty \cdot |x - y|^\alpha 
$$

for $|x-y| \geq C$, so that only smal values are important (at least if you can show that $E$ is bounded).